# trying to figure out how to check to see if value is in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to check to see if the user who's currently logged in has the id of the Post that they're currently viewing in their compare array. Compare is a field in the Users database that contains a serialized array of Post id's. This is one of the things I've tried but it always goes to the else statement

```
<% if User.find(current_user.id).compare.include? @post.id %>
do something
<% else %>
do something else
<% end %>
```

Regards,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use array search:</strike>

```
$key = array_search('USER', $array);
```

Hope this helps!

This is php right?

--
Read the tag... Here is the right answer:

Use: `array.include?(value)`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002226

Answer (score 0):

The `compare` field needs to be deserialized before you can call `include?` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you're using Ruby 1.8. The String class also has an [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-include-3F) method:

> **str.include? other_str => true or false**
>   **str.include? fixnum => true or false**
>   Returns true if *str* contains the given string or character.

So you can do `str.includes? 11` and 1.8.7 will let it by.

In 1.9+, String's [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-include-3F) only understands a string argument:

> **str.include? other_str → true or false**
>   Returns true if *str* contains the given string or character.

So, when you do this:

```
User.find(current_user.id).compare
```

You're getting the serialized form as a string and then looking for a Fixnum in that string. Your `@post.id` is probably out of range of the characters in your serialized data so the `include?` fails. You probably want to unserialize your serialized array in a `compare` override. Or better, store your array data in a separate table when you're dealing with an SQL database underneath.